# Is there a simple equation I can replace this method with?

Tags: equation

You input the day of the week as an int (sunday=0...saturday=6), and it outputs the number of days till the closest saturday.

If it's saturday, it returns 0 because it is saturday.  If it's sunday, it returns -1 because it's 1 day past saturday.  If it's friday, it returns 1 because it's 1 day into the future.

```
   private int nightShiftTransform(int dayOfWeek)
    {
        switch (dayOfWeek)
        {
            case 0:
                return -1;
            case 1:
                return -2;
            case 2:
                return -3;
            case 3:
                return 3;
            case 4:
                return 2;
            case 5:
                return 1;
            case 6:
                return 0;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid day of week");
        }
    }
```

I hate this switch statement, but I can't figure out a simple equation I can replace it with.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'll test out the answers later this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way, if DayOfWeek is between 0 and 6;

```
result = 6 - DayOfWeek - 7*(DayOfWeek < 3);
```

assuming rules in C   (i.e.  an expression of the form `DayOfWeek < 3` yields a value of `0` if false and `1` if true).

Comment: I never even thought of using a boolean value in an equation like that... I like it!

Comment: Since it's C# I had to add a convert to get the boolean to an integer.  Adjusted version is:  6 - DayOfWeek - 7 * Convert.ToInt32(DayOfWeek < 3);

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using C#.
A simple way :

```
   private int nightShiftTransform(int dayOfWeek)
    {
        // ternary expression. You can do an if/else if you prefer
        int result = (dayOfWeek >= 3 ? 6 - dayOfWeek : -(dayOfWeek + 1));
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`equation` isn't a helpful tag.  I'd make the language explicit.  I can't tell if this is Java or C#.

If this were Java, I'd suggest using the `Calendar` constants rather than ints.  I think it's more self documenting and readable.

I can't improve on carndacier's nice ternary expression:

```
package date;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * NightShiftDemo
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519165/is-there-a-simple-equation-i-can-replace-this-method-with
 * @since 11/4/2015 5:21 AM
 */
public class NightShiftDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
            List<String> dates = Arrays.asList("2015-Nov-01", "2015-Nov-02", "2015-Nov-03", "2015-Nov-04", "2015-Nov-05", "2015-Nov-06", "2015-Nov-07");
            for (String date : dates) {
                System.out.println(String.format("date: %s shift: %d", date, nightShiftTransform(formatter.parse(date))));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static int nightShiftTransform(int dayOfWeek) throws Exception
    {
        switch (dayOfWeek)
        {
            case 0:
                return -1;
            case 1:
                return -2;
            case 2:
                return -3;
            case 3:
                return 3;
            case 4:
                return 2;
            case 5:
                return 1;
            case 6:
                return 0;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid day of week");
        }
    }

    public static int nightShiftTransform(Date date) {
        if (date == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("date cannot be null");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return ((dayOfWeek >= Calendar.WEDNESDAY) ? Calendar.SATURDAY - dayOfWeek : -dayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your return is right.
For exemple, if we are "thursday", which is day 4 (dayOfWeek = 4), it is >= Calendar.WEDNESDAY, so will return -dayOfWeek (-4). but the expected result would be 2

Comment: I ran the code. I think the output matched your requirement. I'll check it again tonight.

Comment: One difference with Java: Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7.

Comment: Ok my bad ! not enough experience with Java

Comment: I'm using C# so the other two examples probably cover it.  No time to test right now though.